# Upload Image and save image path to database Lavavel 5.4

Tags: laravel

I am creating a new post on Laravel. But I stuck here to upload an image and save the image path to database. My controller is

```
if($request->hasFile('image'))
        {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $filename = time() . '.'. $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $path = public_path('images');
            $imagepath = $request->image->move($path, $filename);
            $post->image = $imagepath;

        }
```

But it saves path as 'C:\xampp\tmp\php2CF9.tmp'.
What is causing the error? Or are there any better approaches than this?

Comment: can you not just do $post->image = $path."/".$filename;  ....or just save the filename only, and append the path only when displaying.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel can automaically save the correct path for you. First you need to setup the local file storage, if you haven't done so (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration)

Then you can do fancy stuff like:

```
$post = new Post();
$post->image = $request->file('image')->store('image');
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Make sure you have added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form and a `<input type="file">` with field `name="image"`

2) Create a new folder named `images` in your laravel `public` folder.

3) In your `controller`

```
if( $request->hasFile('image')) {
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $path = public_path(). '/images/';
    $filename = time() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $image->move($path, $filename);

    $post->image = $path;
}


$post->save();
```

4) In your `view`

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/FILENAME.EXTENSION') }}">
```

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Whats the point of saving path to DB? U can access to your images by having filename and his extension

```
if($request->hasFile('image'))
{
    $fileNameExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileName = pathinfo($fileNameExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $fileExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $fileNameToStore = $fileName.'_'.time().'.'.$fileExt;
    $pathToStore = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/images',$fileNameToStore);
}

$post = new Post;
if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $post->img = $fileNameToStore;
        }
$post->save();
```

But first u have to create a link with artisan:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

So your images will be stored in:
ProjectName\storage\app\public\images

Comment: My Posts data are stored on DB. So I want to store image path to DB. BTW, this code also did not help. It uploads the image but it does not give image path. And, when I reference image on view, the image url is `code` C:/xampp/tmp/phpBB0.tmp `code`

Answer (score 0):

You can try, It will also store the full path with file name:

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
    $filename = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    $filename = url("/images") .
        "/" . uniqid() .
    $request->file('image')
        ->getClientOriginalName();
            $destinationPath = "images";
    $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
    $post->image = $filename;
        }
```

Comment: But it throws error: Creating default object from empty value

Comment: Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
`(1/1) ErrorException

Creating default object from empty value
in Controller.php (line 134)`

Comment: Updated again please check

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
store into database with file name
$post->image    = $imageName;
display in view
{{ URL::to('/images/'.$post->image) }}
```